PCIe card inserted in a particular slot causes conflict with NIC
I have a Supermicro as-4125gs-tnrt w/ dual Genoa 9174F, 256GB RAM. The NIC model is Supermicro's AOM module running on Intel X710 controller. The OS I'm running is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
Currently, I'm running into an issue where if I plug a PCIe card(Instinct MI200) into slot #11, I lose network connectivity, by that I mean ifconfig shows link down with no IP address (However the LED on the ethernet port is on). If I remove the PCIe card, the network connectivity is restored. This does not happen at any other PCIe slot.
Both NIC controller & MI200 shows up in lspci, but dmesg does gave out a warning about NIC not having enough PCIe lanes to function-- but I don't think that should be the case since I was experimenting with 7 MI200 (in slot 1-4, slot 8-10) earlier before I discover this issue.
Does anyone have any ideas on what could be the cause or any other ideas that I can try?
(Note that I'm currently working with technical support from Supermicro for this issue, but I do want to get to the bottom of this ASAP)

Are you sure the NIC doesn't change bus address and, therefore, names change, so the current configuration needs adjustments? Please, show lspci twice: when the additional card is absent and inserted, so we can compare.

Also, it seems you need to read MoBo manual. There may be explanation, like that if you use certain ports, you have to enable lane split and so on.

@NikitaKipriyanov The bus address does change. Without the card inserted, NIC shows 01:00:0, with the card installed, the NIC shows 02:00:0 and the card shows 01:00:0
Seems like mobo manual is the way to go as well. The generic one out on the official website there doesn't show any details. I will haggle SMIC support for a more in-depth one.
